# Android listview image lag

Tags: android, listview

My app contains a listview which can optionally contain images from a users sd card. It works fine however when any image is loaded there is noticeable lag. I have this in my getView:

```
          BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
             o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
             BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image, o);
             final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;

             //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
             int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
             int scale=1;
             while(true){
                 if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                     break;
                 width_tmp/=2;
                 height_tmp/=2;
                 scale++;
             }

             //Decode with inSampleSize
             BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
             o2.inSampleSize=scale;
             Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image, o2);
             image_main.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT: Replaced the above with this but no images are loading...

```
            class Thumbnailer extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
                    String image;

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                        image_main.setImageBitmap(result);
                    }
                    @Override
                     protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... progress) {
                     }

                    @Override
                    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
                         BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                         o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                         BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image, o);
                         final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;

                         //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
                         int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
                         int scale=1;
                         while(true){
                             if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                                 break;
                             width_tmp/=2;
                             height_tmp/=2;
                             scale++;
                         }
                         //Decode with inSampleSize
                         BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                         o2.inSampleSize=scale;                                  
                         return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image, o2);
                    }
                } 
                new Thumbnailer().execute(image);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show the row with a placeholder image. Do your `BitmapFactory` work in an `AsyncTask`, updating the `ImageView` when done (if the `ImageView` hasn't been recycled and so still needs this particular thumbnail). Cache your work so you do not have to re-do all the scaling again, at least for this incarnation of the `ListView`, perhaps longer if the images will not be changing.

Comment: Thanks for the response..I'm trying with AsyncTask but cannot get it working..I've updated my 1st post to show you what I've done. I've never messed with AsyncTask so I may be doing it incorrectly. I'm pretty much beginner here ;)

Comment: @Paul: It is difficult to help people who decline to say what "cannot get it working" means. Near as I can tell, you are attempting to load every image into a single `ImageView` widget, which seems unlikely. You need to pass into the `AsyncTask` the `ImageView` for the row you are processing with this particular task.

Comment: I think the problem is I'm not actually using the image string I'm passing to the inBackground

Comment: @commonsware sorry it's not displaying images...opens fine and such

Comment: I've changed it to this: BitmapFactory.decodeFile(params, o); But now Bigmapfactory doesn't think params is a string

Comment: new problem though is it acts somewhat strange. If I press something on screen images will shift around and such