# Android AsyncTask Listview problem

Tags: android, listview

I have the below code in my getView. It populates an imageview with an image and it works but not without problems. Problem being that I don't see the image until I click something on the screen. Also if I have more than one image in the listview clicking something on screen will make the images shift around.

```
                    class Thumbnailer extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                            image_main.setImageBitmap(result);
                            image_main.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            image_table.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                        @Override
                         protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... progress) {
                         }

                        @Override
                        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
                             BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                             o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                             BitmapFactory.decodeFile(params[0], o);
                             final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;

                             //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
                             int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
                             int scale=1;
                             while(true){
                                 if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                                     break;
                                 width_tmp/=2;
                                 height_tmp/=2;
                                 scale++;
                             }
                             //Decode with inSampleSize
                             BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                             o2.inSampleSize=scale;                                  
                             return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(params[0], o2);
                        }
                    } 
                    new Thumbnailer().execute(image);
```

Comment: Where is image_main set? This sounds like a problem with reused listitems...

Comment: image_main is set in my getView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think that you cannot do any operation inside an AsyncTask subclass with any view that are attached to the ui, i think the best is to pass a handler to the Thumbnailer class via constructor and dispatch a message for update the image view on the ui thread. on the onPostExecute dispatch a message with the decoded bitmap within message.obj and set the ImageView bitmap on the handleMessage method.

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279255/android-listview-image-lag): near as I can tell, you are attempting to load every image into a single `ImageView` widget, which seems unlikely. You need to pass into the `AsyncTask` the `ImageView` for the row you are processing with this particular task.

> How do I pass a View to Thumbnailer?

Supply it in the constructor, as Mr. Knego suggested.

Comment: Turns out this all runs inside `getView()` of an adapter. Code (probably) returns `imageview` that was just created/edited. The problem is that the changes are done (slowly) inside AsyncTask, while `imageview` is returned immediately. He should just call `imageview.invalidate()` when AsyncTask is done. Right, master?

Comment: Peter I posted my whole code via Pastebin above. I'm pretty newb coder so be easy lol plus been at it all day since like 7am..took me pretty long just to figure out the whole asynctask

Comment: @Peter Knego: "Turns out this all runs inside getView() of an adapter." -- can't, since it's an inner class. "Code (probably) returns imageview that was just created/edited." -- can't, since it's an inner class, so it must be a data member of activity, which is rather wrong. "He should just call imageview.invalidate() when AsyncTask is done." -- should not be needed.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Do you know if you `invalidate()` a view which is inside a parent view, does a parent also get invalidated?

Comment: @Peter Knego: I do not think `invalidate()` goes up the hierarchy. It definitely goes down (invalidating a parent will invalidate the children). However, I have not experimented with this much. It is rather rare that I need to use `invalidate()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare: code is on pastebin. I turns out all this IS inside a `getView()` method of child of CursorAdapter (or SimpleCursorAdapter).

Comment: Yes it is a simplecursoradapter

Answer (score 0):

Try passing a `View` to your `Thumbnailer` via a constructor, and then call `view.invalidate()` as last line in `onPostExecute`. This should force `View` to redraw itself.

Comment: How do I pass a View to Thumbnailer? Search around but couldn't really find anything.

Comment: What is `getView` returning? image_main?

Comment: image_main is the imageview that in the listview row

Comment: Anyhow, `new Thumbnailer().execute(image)` returns immediately. Bitmaps are loaded in a separate background thread. If you return from `getView()` immediately after `execute()` them you are most probably returning nothing (null) since data is not yet there.

Comment: The solution is to call `image_main.invalidate()` on the last line of `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: I put that on the last line of onPostExecute but results are the same. This is my whole getView http://pastebin.com/YT4AEb9p Without AsyncTask everything works perfectly but there is noticeable lag.

Comment: I just read the code. I think I know what it does ;). You should tell `View v` to redraw itself after you loaded all the bitmaps. So, call `v.invalidate()` as the last line of `onPostExecute()`.